# fwrite function writes nothing to the file

Tags: php

I am trying to write data into a txt file, but It won't work. there is no error. it just won't work. 
here is the code

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
        $hour = $_REQUEST['hour'];
        $family = $_REQUEST['family'];
        $how = $_REQUEST['how'];
        $will = $_REQUEST['will'];
        $fun = $_REQUEST['fun'];
        $kind = $_REQUEST['kind'];
        $device = $_REQUEST['device'];
        $study = $_REQUEST['study'];
        $agree = $_REQUEST['agree'];
        $text = "hour :" . $hour . "<br />" . "family" . $family . "<br />" . "تطابفق با درس" . $how . "<br />" . "سرگرمی های غیر مجازی : " . $will . "<br />" . "نوع سرگرمی :" . $fun . "<br />" . "kind :  " . $kind . "<br />" . "device " . $device . "<br />" . "اثیر بر درس" . $study . "<br />" . "کنترل " . $agree . "<br />" ;
        fopen('/1.txt', "r");
        fwrite('/1.txt',"hour :" . $hour . "<br />" . "family" . $family . "<br />" . "تطابفق با درس" . $how . "<br />" . "سرگرمی های غیر مجازی : " . $will . "<br />" . "نوع سرگرمی :" . $fun . "<br />" . "kind :  " . $kind . "<br />" . "device " . $device . "<br />" . "اثیر بر درس" . $study . "<br />" . "کنترل " . $agree . "<br />");
        fclose('/1.txt');

    }
```

do note that there is an "else" that includes all the aforementioned input fields that I used in the code , and that I am executing on localhost.
thanks

Comment: Have you checked the `fwrite` documentation? What should be the first argument and what have you passed? Then - check the `fopen` documentation and find out what `'r'` flag means. After that google something about absolute and relative filesystem paths.

Comment: You're opening it for (r)ead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot write to it since you are opening it as read-only:

```
$handle = fopen('/1.txt', "r");
```

Instead:

```
$handle = fopen('/1.txt', "w"); // to write only, if you need to read and write use 'w+'
```

You also need to store fopen in a $handle so you can write to it later.

Documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Now the first parameter for fwrite should be `$handle`:

```
fwrite($handle, "hour :" . $hour . "<br />" . "family" . $family . "<br />" . "تطابفق با درس" . $how . "<br />" . "سرگرمی های غیر مجازی : " . $will . "<br />" . "نوع سرگرمی :" . $fun . "<br />" . "kind :  " . $kind . "<br />" . "device " . $device . "<br />" . "اثیر بر درس" . $study . "<br />" . "کنترل " . $agree . "<br />");
```

Documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

At the end you should also close with `$handle`:

```
fclose($handle);
```

Documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the file as read-only, with the `r`use `w` instead. And you need to pass [`fwrite`](https://www.php.net/fwrite) the return of `fopen` as first argument, not the filename:

```
$f = fopen('/1.txt', "w");
fwrite($f,"hour :" . $hour . "<br />" . "family" . $family . "<br />" . "تطابفق با درس" . $how . "<br />" . "سرگرمی های غیر مجازی : " . $will . "<br />" . "نوع سرگرمی :" . $fun . "<br />" . "kind :  " . $kind . "<br />" . "device " . $device . "<br />" . "اثیر بر درس" . $study . "<br />" . "کنترل " . $agree . "<br />");
fclose($f);
```

Comment: This answer is the most correct, since it points to both `w` and using a handler

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in a 'w' to write to a file.

```
$handle = fopen('/1.txt', "w");
```

Passing in 'r' makes it so you are opening a 'read-only' file.

Comment: Still need a file handler.

Comment: But that wasn't the only thing.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler:

```
file_put_contents('/1.txt', $text);
```